# n8n in GitHub pipeline fails to expose port

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, github-actions, fastapi

We have a docker compose which we need for testing of our code. When we run it locally (macOS, different hosts) it works fine, however as soon as we run it on a GitHub action runner, it fails with

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5678): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/credentials (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3d28e3d810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

The affected service is an n8n container, which should expose an HTTP API, which also works locally.

```
  n8n:
    image: docker.n8n.io/n8nio/n8n
    ports:
      - "5678:5678"
    environment:
      - N8N_HOST=n8n:5678
      - N8N_PORT=5678
      - N8N_PROTOCOL=http
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - DB_TYPE=postgresdb
      - DB_TABLE_PREFIX=n8n_
      - DB_POSTGRESDB_DATABASE=n8n
    volumes:
      - ./DOCKER/n8n/data:/home/node/.n8n
      - ./DOCKER/n8n/files:/files
```

We try to access this with our FastAPI API, using the python requests library. What could be the difference between these two systems? The docker compose is the same, env files are being reset by our testing script.

**Update**

I minimalized the reproducible issue to the following:

```
curl --fail http://localhost:8080 || exit 1
curl --fail http://localhost:5678/api/v1/docs/ || exit 1
```

In my docker compose I have two services, one on 8080 which is working and n8n which is not working. The above code fails in the second line with error `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5678 after 0 ms: Connection refused`. I also tried switching ports in case the GitHub actions already use this port.

Comment: Are you testing with a Fast API that is also running in the Github Actions environment?

Comment: @RichardScholtens FastAPI is not running in the GitHub Actions environment, only the pytest for it.

Comment: There's plenty of things that can be different... Can you show your Actions definitions? How are you starting this container? Does it start successfully? Are there any error log messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this guide on the official docs (thanks to this tread: https://github.com/n8n-io/n8n/issues/8272) volume mounts should be used as well the hostname pointed to should be n8n not localhost as described below. In this case to not obscure the folder structure etc. It was done in the form:

volumes:
n8n_data:
driver: local
driver_opts:
type: none
o: bind
device: ./DOCKER/n8n/data
Edit your code to use the host n8n instead of localhost.

The service is bound to a host named n8n not localhost.

From https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservices:

> If you configure your job to run in a container, or your step uses container actions, you don't need to map ports to access the service or action. Docker automatically exposes all ports between containers on the same Docker user-defined bridge network. You can directly reference the service container by its hostname. The hostname is automatically mapped to the label name you configure for the service in the workflow.

Comment: This works! On my local machine it doesn't work with using n8n but only with localhost, but on the runner it is the other way round.

Comment: @creyD Great to hear :) Please accept my answer.

Comment: Sorry to say, but as there was a new issue, I thought this solved it. However it now says "requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='n8n', port=5678): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/credentials (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f348049d4d0>: Failed to resolve 'n8n' ([Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution)")" and I am pretty sure that this is actually the same issue

Comment: Where is this error happening?

Comment: I have pytest tests which check the connection to the n8n and different other tools, within these tests there is a request call to this API which fails.

Comment: I added a smaller example to my question, would appreciate if you could check it out.

Comment: please post the output when you use n8n hostname with curl instead of localhost.

Comment: I continued it in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77780580/why-is-n8n-failing-in-a-github-pipeline-but-not-locally The curl just came back empty, as the service is not up.

Comment: So if you want you can update your answer to that, then I will mark it as accepted again. It was just the service which wasn't up. But please keep your initial answer too, as I solved part of the problem.